# Docker + postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker

Суть воопроса в следующем
у меня есть существующая база данных
мне нужно создать из нее докер образ
Собственно ворпос в том как это сделать
База данных постргресс,ос винда
Докер и виртуал бокс стоят.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы запустили контейнер, то тогда вам надо зайти в него:

```
docker exec -it 'название_контейнера' sh
```

дальше вы логинитесь под учётной записью postgres

```
su - postgres
```

ну и теперь можно восстановить из вашего дампа БД

```
pg_restore -d name_db 'путь по которому вы подмонтировали дамп внутри контейнера'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно сделать дамп БД и влить его в развёрнутый под докером постгрес.

Либо линковать каталог БД с хоста в контейнер.

Comment: Да ,я все это сделал,у меня есть образ ,я запустил контейнер с этим образом постргрес.есть файл test.backup ,запускаю gitbash и хочу восстановить там эту базу но ни одна команда не работает,можете написать как в гитбаше прописать это восстановление

Comment: $ psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5432 -U postgres < C:\pgsql\javatest.backup
bash: C:pgsqljavatest.backup: No such file or directory
вот так не получается

Comment: postgres=# pg_restore -d test  C:/PostgreSQL-11/javatest.backup;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_restore"
LINE 1: pg_restore -d test  C:/PostgreSQL-11/javatest.backup;
так тоже не получается

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд проще это сделать через интерактивный ввод

```bash
docker exec -i docker_container_name psql db_name user_name < /path/to/dump.sql
```